# Android:clipChildren Causes Custom View's Background To Draw Full Height Of Screen

Tags: android, background, drag-and-drop, android-edittext, clipping

I have custom `EditText`s and I  noticed their backgrounds draw wrong when they leave their parents. So I used `android:clipChildren="false"` on their parent. That works fine. They draw correctly when partially out of their parent now.

This gave me a new problem though. On older devices (< Android 2.3? Not confirmed what the max version is for this issue), the background doesn't get clipped to it's padding. The `EditText` backgrounds are now drawing to the full height/width of the screen. This only happens on the initial layout.

Has anyone experienced this before? It's really weird. I don't get why the background only draws wrong when using `android:clipChildren="false"` and only on some devices. I need that though since my `EditText`s can be dragged around and need to keep drawing outside their parent container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran across the same problem. It was caused by having ColorDrawables as background (a StateListDrawable (`<selector>`) containing several `@color/...` items, to be exact).

It looks like this was fixed in Android 3.2.4-r1 (commit [95930e1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/95930e13faac8c17dabfaa1478089baa772f091b)).

Before that, the class comment used to say:

> Note that a ColorDrawable [...] ignores the Bounds, meaning it will draw everywhere in the current clip even if setBounds(...) was called with a smaller area.

This was removed, and the `draw(Canvas)` method changed to respect the bounds.

---

As a workaround, if you need to support older Android versions, you can use a ShapeDrawable with a solid color to get the same behaviour:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/your_background_color"/>    
</shape>
```

Comment: Actually, your question was helping me figure out what was going on in the first place, so thanks a lot for asking!

Comment: I am pretty sure that is what I ended up doing. It took me a while to solve this problem, so I forgot I asked the question! I will probably mark your answer as correct, because I'm almost positive the shape drawable approach is what I did.

Comment: Thanks. Above all I just wanted to leave this for others to find, it sure took me long enough!

Answer (score 0):

We had a 2.3.4 device where this issue was causing an ImageView to cover everything above it in the LinearLayout it was contained in.
The fix was to create the ShapeDrawable mentioned above and use that as the background to the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/your_background_color"/>    
</shape>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/this_is"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/a_rectangle_shape_drawable"
    android:contentDescription="@string/an_image_view"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/an_icon" />
```